# Sharepoint 2010 migration required accounts

Tags: 2010, migration

Planning for a Sharepoint 2010 database attach migration what accounts and roles are required to be set for a successful migration ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Administrator account is required to migrate site.

Answer (score 0):

You'd first need to specify what migration option you'll be using. In-place, database attach? Review the account plan for SharePoint 2010: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445.aspx. And - of course - you'll need administrative farm access.